# Semantic-ui trying to run gulp build but none of its dependencies are installed

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I'm trying to install them all manually one at a time, so hopefully it works, but why is this necessary? the documentation asks me to run the command from within the semantic folder where npm install does nothing to rectify it, and gulp build fails because none of the dependencies are there? Scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I reinstalled in a different folder, and tried again and it worked properly without intervention this time. Not sure what went wrong.